# Appium Inspector throws error : Failed to connect to server, Pls check that it is running

Tags: appium, appium-inspector

I installed Appium and I'm trying to run the Appium on a hybrid app, but my Appium Inspector is not getting connected.

Comment: Am trying to run on an android device..please help

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it´s a bit late but I hope it will useful for other colleges

With an Android emulator running. On the last appium version (1.4.13.1) on Windows8

1.-Run Appium as administrator. Tap on Android icon
-->1.1.-Check you have the correct application path nothing more have to be selected on application tag but, Package, Wait for packages and other fields will be filled automatically after select the .apk
-->1.2.- On "Launch device" tag , you have to select one, in my case is Nexus_5, nothing more is selected.
-->1.3.- Capabilities, Platform name: Android.  Automation mane : Appium  . Platform Version 6.0(Marshmallow)
-->1.4.- Advanced tag nothing will be selected
2.- Tap on Play icon
3.- Tap on magnifying glass

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have configured the environment variable `ANDROID_HOME`:

```
ANDROID_HOME='your android sdk directory'
```

Answer (score 0):

To start the Appium inspector, you need to make sure your scripts are running at that time.

Comment: I am doing website testing and the script works fine..it launches the chrome and site successfully..but the inspector isn't capturing anything..when i click on the inspector..it gives the error "Failed to connect to to server, Pls check that it is running"